# Flask-JQuery Value not receiving in Server

Tags: jquery, python, flask

Am trying to pass a string from JQuery to Flask

Client Code -

```
 $("input").keyup(function(){
      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_get_Data', {
            a: $('input[name="getName"]').val()
          }, function(data) {
            $('#result').text(data.result);
          });
  });
```

Server Code -

```
@app.route('/_get_Data')
def getNewData():
    newValue= str(request.args.get('getName'))
    print newValue //Line Here Prints None, though String Value is passed from Client Code
    return jsonify(result=str(newValue))
```

The Value returned from `str(request.args.get('getName'))` is always None

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be you need to replace this:

```
request.args.get('getName')
```

with this:

```
request.args.get('a')
```

or change this at the client:

```
{ getName : $('input[name="getName"]').val() }
```

because you are passing `{a: $('input[name="getName"]').val()}` and you are trying to get `getName` from the request which is not available there, so you have to target `'a'` instead of `'getName'`.